# Apply a class based on the page

Tags: jquery, css

I need to apply a class ".selected" to a navigation item when the user is on the corresponding page, so that when the user clicks on "Products", it goes to the products page but the Products nav item remains selected. How can I accomplish this using jQuery? I suppose I would need to get the URL of the page an apply the style to the corresponding nav item, correct?

Comment: You should maybe do this server side

Comment: I agree. Write out a CSS class server side in the markup. Then all the page states can be expressed in CSS and no JS is needed to set the selected page style.

Answer (score 1):

assuming the element you want styled `.selected` has an id same as the html file currently in the browser:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ...
  var page = window.location.href.match(/\/(\w+).htm/)[1];
  $('#' + page).addClass('selected');
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you'll be doing some sort of AJAX system where you won't be reloading the menu on every click, otherwise this should definitely be done server side. If not, you can use the following

**HTML**

```
<ul id='main'>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
    <li>menu</li>
</ul>​​​
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('ul#main > li').click(function() {
        $('ul#main > li.selected').removeClass('selected');
        this.setAttribute('class','selected');
}​​​​​​​​​);​
```

Here's a link to try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/6zpJX/

Comment: would be easy to just, `$('ul#main > li').click(function() { $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected'); }​​​​​​​​​);​` ^^,

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example, if you wish to match the entire URL ('http://example.com/mydir/mypage.html'):

```
  $(function() {
    var url = window.location;
    $('a[href="' + url + '"]').addClass('selected');
  });
```

Or, to match the path ('/mydir/mypage.html'):

```
  $(function() {
    var url = window.location.path;
    $('a[href="' + url + '"]').addClass('selected');
  });
```